# TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize a sentence into words. In the following code I am trying to split the sentence into words using some predefined split parameters.

```
import re
_WORD_SPLIT = re.compile(b"([.,!?\"':;)(])")

def basic_tokenizer(sentence):
    words = []
    for space_separated_fragment in sentence.strip().split():
        words.extend(_WORD_SPLIT.split(space_separated_fragment))
    return [w for w in words if w]

basic_tokenizer("I live, in Mumbai.")
```

It shows me an error:

> TypeError: cannot use a bytes pattern on a string-like object.

Earlier this code was properly working for me but when I reinstall and install `tensorflow`, it shows me an error. I also used the `.decode()` function but it did not solve my problem.

I am using python3.6 on Ubuntu.

Comment: `b"([.,!?\"':;)(])"` -> `r"([.,!?\"':;)(])"`

Comment: Check my answer below and see if it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You gave a byte object while compiling the `re` and while calling it you are giving a string object `space_seprated_fragment`

convert it to bytes while passing it to the `_WORD_SPLIT` :

```
import re
_WORD_SPLIT = re.compile(b"([.,!?\"':;)(])")

def basic_tokenizer(sentence):
    words = []
    for space_separated_fragment in sentence.strip().split():
        words.extend(_WORD_SPLIT.split(space_separated_fragment.encode()))
    return [w for w in words if w]

basic_tokenizer("I live, in Mumbai.")
```

Comment: Note that this outputs a list of byte strings: `[b'I', b'live', b',', b'in', b'Mumbai', b'.']`

Answer (score 1):

`re.compile` takes a normal string. [re.compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile)

```
import re
_WORD_SPLIT = re.compile("([.,!?\"':;)(])")

def basic_tokenizer(sentence):
    words = []
    for space_separated_fragment in sentence.strip().split():
        words.extend(_WORD_SPLIT.split(space_separated_fragment))
    return [w for w in words if w]
print(basic_tokenizer("I live, in Mumbai."))
#['I', 'live', ',', 'in', 'Mumbai', '.']
```